# System.InvalidOperationException: You must either set Authority or IntrospectionEndpoint error in .net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

[image]

[image]

As mention in image i have below packages but when execute getting error

Comment: Hi @sandy, how is your Startup.cs like?  Have you added `options.ApiSecret` to `AddIdentityServerAuthentication`? Refer to:https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1745

Answer (score 3):

When a malformed JWT is passed to a .NET Core 2.0 API using IdentityServer Authentication and a 500 status code is returned instead of a 401, setting

`options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;`

in the `Startup.cs` > `ConfigureServices()` solved this problem. [Source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1627)

```
public class Startup 
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
    {
        //...

        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["Authorization:Authority"];
            options.ApiName = configuration["Authorization:Audience"];
            options.EnableCaching = true;
            options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding  options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt fixed my issue. Thanks!